# Protect page behind Chargebee login without going over API rate limit when you have many users?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth

I'm looking at using Chargebee to handle subscriptions. Chargebee also gives you the ability to protect a page you host behind a Chargebee login where you ask a user to login via a OAUTH workflow and verify the OAUTH token you receive is valid with an API call (this is an older API but you can ask to use it apparently):
https://support.chargebee.com/support/solutions/articles/223577-how-do-i-protect-my-pages-using-chargebee-s-customer-portal-login-

However, it says here that each site gets rate limited to 150 API calls per minute:
https://support.chargebee.com/support/discussions/topics/38210

How then is it practical to use the login system above with such a low rate limit? If I had say 10K users and a small number tend to login around 9am on a Monday, I would easily go over the rate limit.

Am I missing something here? Am I using Chargebee in a way that's not intended? How are you suppose to protect a page behind a Chargebee login when you have thousands of users?